# User List of a Microsoft Access accdb hosted on a remote server

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Microsoft Access application (accdb) hosted on a server that all users remote into.  I'm using the code from [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/285822/how-to-determine-who-is-logged-on-to-a-database-by-using-microsoft-jet) to list users.  The problem is that the LOGIN_NAME for all the users is Admin [Pic of list of users all named Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFoiC.png).

Is there a setting on the server I can change that uses the Login ID of each user instead of Admin?

Answer (score 1):

That code refers to the *workgroup security* of the JET engine, which was abandoned in Access 2010 and still is.

You will have to obtain the logon name of the session. The extremely simple method in VBA is:

```
Username = Environ("username")
```

You can also use an API call for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should know also that an Access application must be split into 2 files (front & back) for simultaneous multi user deployment.  Each user must be assigned their own unique front file.  All front files link to the single back file that holds the tables.  No one directly uses the back file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sufficient privileges to open an Administrative Command Prompt on the remote server, I suggest the `OpenFiles` command. You could also look at the SysInternals `PsFile` command. Both should tell you the real usernames of all users attached to an Access database file.